# sockJS own event names

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sockjs

I am using sockjs-node and I want to emit on my own events(using conn.write(...) i am able only to emit on 'data') is it possible to do so? And how?

```
echo.on('connection', function(conn) {
conn.emit('message', {msg:'xd'}); //I know that it doesnt work, just i would like to know is it possible to achieve emitting on my own events using sockjs
conn.on('close', function() {
    console.log('close');
});
conn.end();
});
```

for example, sth similar to the line with conn.emit

Answer (score 1):

sockJS works like a webSocket where it just delivers data packets to you.  If you want a messaging layer on top of that, you could build one fairly easily, but it is not part of sockJS itself.

To build your own message layer, you could just built a simple abstraction on top of the sockJS transport that supports `.emit(msg, data)` and then sends a message over sockJS that has two parts to it, the message name and the data, perhaps converted to JSON for sending the JSON over sockJS.

On the receiving end, you would do just the opposite and you could have your own eventEmitter so you'd receive the sockJS data, break it apart into message name and data and then emit the data to the message name.

FYI, it might just make sense to use socket.io since it is already a messaging layer on top of webSocket (and a few other features such as auto-reconnect).

Comment: Well, i tried using socket.io, however I keep getting 400 bad request having no idea why, that's why I decided to use sockJS, which works for me. Can you provide any example of supporting .emit(msg,data)?

Comment: @Ajris -Well, if it was me, I'd just fix my problem with socket.io.  It works fine for tens of thousands of people so it's just a matter of debugging your installation to fix things.  I don't personally have time right now to write you a messaging layer for sockJS.  I'd suggest you post an new question and show your code with an attempt to use socket.io, describe the problem and get some help fixing that.